# connexion serve swagger ui at another url

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, connexion

We are using `connexion` to serve the swagger ui. We are using the openapi 3.0.0 specification. Here is a small part of our `swagger.yml`:

```
openapi: 3.0.0

servers:
  - url: /

paths:
  /resource:
    ...
  /resource2:
    ...
```

in this case the ui is served at `/ui`. We are however using nginx to redirect all requests to `/resource` into this container. We would like swagger-ui to be served at `/some-subdir/ui` instead of at `/ui`, in order to be able to redirect the requests to the right container.

### trial 1

```
openapi: 3.0.0

servers:
  - url: /app

paths:
  /resource:
    ...
  /resource2:
    ...
```

which works, except that the resources are now served at `/app/resource` etc, while the same resource might in the future be served by another app, so we don't want the app name to appear in the URL of the resources (while it might be acceptable just for the swagger-ui).

### trial 2

I found that, when constructing the connexion app, I could specify the `swagger_url` option:

```
options = {
    'swagger_url': '/app/ui'
}
connexion_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./', options=options)
```

now the swagger-ui is served at `/app/ui`, but the ui is trying to serve `/openapi.json` which is not reachable since not under `/app` (or any other subdir).

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, there is another (well hidden) option to change the path to the `openapi.json`, the combination with `swagger_url` works:

```
options = {
    'swagger_url': '/app/ui',
    'openapi_spec_path': '/app/openapi.json'
}
connexion_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./', options=options)
```